# Is there a way to know how much time does my program takes to finish? C code

Tags: c, time

I am looking for a way to know how much time will my C program use, preferably before I run it, but if this cannot be known before, then after it has ended.

Is there a way?

Comment: If in Linux, `man time`.  Try `$ time ./a.out` or something like that.  You could, of couse, use `clock_gettime ()` to time portions of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After, yes. On most (all?) UNIX-y systems, you can use this:

```
time ./myprog
```

Before, no, because the program could depend on external input.  [The halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) might also be an obstacle to finding the amount of time a program would take to execute beforehand.

Comment: The `time` utility is part of Posix, so if it's missing then in some sense the system isn't UNIX-y. Or to be precise, maybe it is UNIX-y but doesn't support the "user portability utilities". Which basically means it doesn't have a UNIX-y command line UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clock()`:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 int main() {
 clock_t start, stop;
 start = clock();

 /* Your code */

 stop = clock();
 printf("Run time: %f",(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I believe `clock ()` gives us the CPU time.  There is a rather large difference between the result of `clock ()` and `clock_gettime ()`, so in my code I always test with both the functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
time -f "%e" -o Output.txt ./a.out
```

It will store the total execution time to execute `./a.out` to the file `Output.txt`.